# Expect Script - varying sends

Tags: shell, tcl

I'm working on expect script to call a installer.sh 
For a neat installations , it works fine.

But when the installer fails for pre-checks, the order of the send differs and i have no control on the order.

```
  spawn ./Installer.sh
expect "change? (Y/N)"
  send "Y\r"
  expect "path"
  send "$path\r"
  expect "Enter selection"
  send "1\r"
  expect "path"
  send "$path 
  exit 0
```

After 2nd expect "path", the installer validates internally and proceeds with step3 and continues and finishes.

But if after second expect path , installer pre-checks fails then it exists and prompts for last step ie for the path again.

currently when the script displays after exiting and prompts for 4th, it continues to send the 3rd response which is irrelevant.Does the script does not validate fr the match expect string?

```
  Error :
  "No Space. Exiting.
  **Path: 1**
  cp: cannot create regular file `1': Permission denied
  send: spawn id exp5 not open
      while executing
  "send "path\r""
```

The shell script exits for various reasons and prompts for last send.

Is there a way to get the last display message expect_out while the session is ongoing and read it and continue based on it.

```
spawn shellscript
expect_1
send_1
expect_2
send_2
--sh stops and displays exiting...
if expect_out(buffer)=exiting
then
expect_4
send_4
else
expect_3
send_3
expect_4
send_4
exit
```

Comment: Maybe work with "catch"?

Comment: I would think about using the `expect_before` command to see an "Error" message.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you probably need is the ability to `expect` several different things at once. Fortunately, this is quite easy to do.

```
expect {
    "change? (Y/N)" {
        # Something in here to respond to this case
        # This bit is just code, but could be effectively empty too
    }
    "Exiting" {
        # Now we've detected that the installer failed
        send_user "oh no!\n"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

When using this form, you can restart the current `expect` from within a handler script by finishing it with `exp_continue`. As usual, you've got to think careful about what actual patterns to match.

Comment: thanks will try .`expect: does " \r\nY\r\n\r\nPlease enter path: " (spawn_id exp5) match exact string "Please enter  path$"? no
expect: does " \r\nY\r\n\r\nPlease enter  path: \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match exact string  "Please enter path$"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "/proj/XXX/YYYY\r" to { exp5 }
expect: does " \r\nY\r\n\r\nPlease enter  path: \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern  "Exiting"? no
/proj/XXX/YYYY` expect appends previous lines recursively. i tried multiple regex but everytime timeout occurs.